# Font awesome icons not appearing on my page

Tags: html

I am currently trying to get icons to appear on my web page but it appears that there's a problem. On my homepage the icons work, on my about page however, all that appears are squares. Here is the corresponding code:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font- 
 awesome.min.css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

         <div class="footer-icons">

            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>

        </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like the actual font is missing, check the console (F12) for errors.

Comment: Your font-awesome cdn has typos

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to state the obvious,  but given that you get different outcomes in different contexts your question should indicate what is different about those contexts. The problem doesn't appear to be in this code, alone.